# File origin and log history

Tags: windows-10, macos, ubuntu, filesystems, file-management

Before I start, English is not my primary language, so please excuse my lack of sentence structure and grammar.

I am trying to find out where a .docx file originated from and what places it has been through.
What I mean is, I want more information than what "right click > properties > details" (windows) and "right click > get info > more info" (Mac) gives me.

I want to see the entire log path and history. Rough example; Dropbox 10.10.19, Google Drive 12.11.19...

Is there a program or code I can run to get this information - if so, is there a way to strip this information from the file? I have systems with macOS Catalina, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10, so if there is a way on any of these operating systems, I'd be delighted for any help I can get.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer: It is not possible.

Comment: _Before I start, English is not my primary language, so please excuse my lack of sentence structure and grammar_ When we see this, we know the question _will_ have near-impeccable grammar and phrasing. No apology needed. Your question is lucid and valid.

Comment: If *every* computer added some bytes describing their operating system, every program on the system it might have passed through, and various other specifications to a file it saw then we would have run out of storage capacity on every system ever created the moment the internet was turned on.

Answer (score 0):

*entire log path and history.*?

Afraid not. Office does not retain that.

*is there a way to strip this information from the file*?

Export to RTF or Save as RTF, which will discard that information.